# React and fuse-box: production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is quite simple: I'm working on a simple React app, using Fusebox. In my Chrome browser, I have the React plugin that tells me I'm not running a production build (**even when I try to run a production build**).

The plugin points on that link: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build

When I check about webpack, the only things to do are to run everything with `NODE_ENV` set to `'production'` and add the `Uglify` plugin.

When I do the same in Fusebox, I keep getting the same warning about 'not running production build', so I assume something is wrong.

Here is my fuse.js:

```
const { FuseBox, BabelPlugin, CSSPlugin, EnvPlugin, UglifyJSPlugin, WebIndexPlugin } = require("fuse-box");

const prod = true;

const fuse = FuseBox.init({
    homeDir: "src",
    output: "docs/$name",
    sourceMaps: !prod,
    plugins: [
        EnvPlugin({ NODE_ENV: prod ? 'production' : 'development' }),
        CSSPlugin(),
        BabelPlugin({
            config: {
                sourceMaps: !prod,
                presets: [ "es2015" ],
                plugins: [ "transform-react-jsx" ],
            }
        }),
        WebIndexPlugin({ path: ".", template: 'src/index.html' }),
        prod && UglifyJSPlugin()
    ]
});

if(!prod) {
    fuse.dev();
}

let vendor = fuse.bundle("vendor.js").instructions("~index.js");
let app = fuse.bundle("app.js").instructions(">[index.js]");

if(!prod) {
    app.watch().hmr();
}

fuse.run();
```

Do you have any idea why I still get the warning? How can I fix this to get a production build for React? (I suppose it is a stupid question but I just cannot see the solution here...)
Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it finally!

It seems everything was in the Quantum plugin. With this configuration, the website is validated as production-ready:

```
const { FuseBox, BabelPlugin, CSSPlugin, QuantumPlugin, WebIndexPlugin } = require('fuse-box');

const prod = true;

const fuse = FuseBox.init({
    homeDir: 'src',
    output: 'docs/$name',
    sourceMaps: !prod,
    plugins: [
        CSSPlugin(),
        BabelPlugin({
            config: {
                sourceMaps: !prod,
                presets: [ 'es2015' ],
                plugins: [ 'transform-react-jsx' ]
            }
        }),
        WebIndexPlugin({ path: '.', template: 'src/index.html' }),
        prod && QuantumPlugin({
            removeExportsInterop: false,
            uglify: true
        })
    ]
});

if(!prod) {
    fuse.dev();
}

let vendor = fuse.bundle('vendor.js').instructions('~index.js');
let app = fuse.bundle('app.js').instructions('>[index.js]');

if(!prod) {
    app.watch().hmr();
}

fuse.run();
```

No need to add `EnvPlugin` and `UglifyPlugin`, the `QuantumPlugin` does the job for you! I'm not pretty sure about the configuration I passed to this plugin, I'll fetch some more documentation. I've found inspiration thank to this page: https://github.com/fuse-box/react-example/blob/master/fuse.js.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of additional things that you are not doing that may be causing React plugin's complaints. In production mode you can apply the following babel transformations for additional optimizations:

1. ["transform-react-remove-prop-types"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types). Most likely cause, because prop types just add unnecessary weight to your code.
2. ["transform-react-constant-elements"](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-constant-elements/)
3. ["transform-react-inline-elements"](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-inline-elements/)

Comment: I've tried it but I keep getting the warning from the React plugin... :( I wonder about the EnvPlugin, because from what I read from the react's documentation, it should work.

Comment: @sjahan Try adding [babel-preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) as well. Bear in mind that `transform-react-jsx` becomes redundant.

Comment: Same result :( i've added it, then i tried to remove `transform-react-jsx`, no progress :/